# Laravel sql query continuously running forever

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Its my first time using laravel and im building this application where i have the following query.

```
   $productDetails = DB::table('products')->where('products.id_product', $id_product)
        ->leftJoin('product_options', $id_product, '=', 'product_options.id_product')->where('product_options.is_active', '1')
        ->leftJoin('options', 'product_options.id_option', '=', 'options.id_option')->where('options.is_active','1')
        ->get();
```

Everytime i load the page that calls this query it just keeps spinning forever. The data is not too much so i know its not because the query is taking too long but something is causing this. I have turned debug on but nothing happens i see no errors in the log or anywhere else.

If i comment out the join statement the query returns results but as soon as i add back any of the left join statements it just continues spinning. Does anyone see anything wrong with the query above?

Comment: Can you provide us with your DB schema as well, so we can see your indices...

Comment: You probably have something wrong in the application. Open up the debug tool of your favorite browser (F12 in chrome) go to the network tab and see what's happening to your ajax call. There should be something there about an error if error reporting is enabled for php and laravel. If not then you should at least see an error 500 for an internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of `where` operator is `where('column', 'operator', $value)`

So, you must add the operator in your query (3 additions).

---

**EDIT**

Sorry, I hadn't noticed that can skip the equality operator.

Nonetheless, I think you need a [Many To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) (belogsToMany-belogsToMany) relationship. It is more easier and more clean.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can now join using the $id_product variable passed to the function and instead have to join using the id_product value from the query.

so it has to be

```
 $productDetails = DB::table('products')->where('products.id_product', $id_product)
    ->leftJoin('product_options', 'products.id_product', '=', 'product_options.id_product')->where('product_options.is_active', '1')
    ->leftJoin('options', 'product_options.id_option', '=', 'options.id_option')->where('options.is_active','1')
    ->get();
```